# Neighbourhood of infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

In the extended complex plane, does there exist a neighbourhood of $\infty$ which contains the origin?

My feeling is that there is no neighborhood of $\infty$ containing the origin. But this defies my intuition since for example a neighborhood of any point in the complex plane can be made to include the origin by choosing the radius large enough! Any clarification please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complement of any compact set is a neighborhood of $\infty$. So $\mathbb C_{\infty} \setminus \{z: |z-2| \leq 1\}$ is a neighborhood of $\infty$ other than $\mathbb C_{\infty}$ itself which contains $0$.

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Neighbourhoods don't need to be small. For example, the entire space is always a neighbourhood of every of its points. So the extended complex plane is a neighbourhood of $\infty$ containing $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking for a non trivial example.